# Is it possible to nest select expressions in jq?

Tags: jq

I have this input data:

```
{
    "xs": [
        {
            "id": "a",
            "ts": "2023-01-03"
        },
        {
            "id": "b",
            "ts": "2023-01-01"
        },
        {
            "id": "c",
            "ts": "2023-01-02"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to select only element `id=c` because it is the *first* element, with a date greater than `id=b`'s, if you sort the elements in `xs` by their `ts` field.

This works:

```
.xs | sort_by(.ts) | map(select(.ts > "2023-01-01")) | first
```

but I don't want to hard code the date. I want to use another select to find it:

```
.xs | sort_by(.ts) | map(select(.ts > select(.id == "b").ts)) | first
```

that however returns the empty list.

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VJrQ-VDm4OY)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in two steps, store the temporary result in a variable and use it again in the next `select()`

```
.xs                                | 
sort_by(.ts)                       | 
( 
  map(select(.id == "b").ts) as $d | 
  map(select(.ts > $d[]))          | 
  first 
)
```

jqplay - [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9I744rHIL18)

Comment: One suggestion I would make is to use `any/2` for the condition `.ts > $d[]`. The `[]` can make it hard to debug when using it in different scenarios and using `any` would force it to resolve to a single value.